# AWS CodeBuild golang build fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

When I run the following command: `- go build -o app` I get the following error (for multiple dependencies) : `main.go:21:2: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOPATH)
    /codebuild/output/src324986171/src/github.com/gorilla/mux`

Meaning the codebuild fails. Any idea how I can fix this, or in general where the problem is ?
Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
After adding `go get ./...` to the build I get the following error for all my local packages:`# cd .; git clone https://github.com/aristotle/dbhelper /go/src/github.com/aristotle/dbhelper
Cloning into '/go/src/github.com/aristotle/dbhelper'...`

My buildspec.yml looks like this:

```js
version: 0.2

phases:
  install: 
    commands:
      - echo CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR - $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
      - echo GOPATH - $GOPATH
      - echo GOROOT - $GOROOT
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Getting packages
      - go get ./...
      - echo Compiling the Go code...
      - go build -o app main.go
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - app
```

Comment: it looks like your are missing the dependency `gorilla/mux` ... Any chance that you run something like `go get ./...` before your build?

Comment: Yes I could, but is that not somewhat tedious when you have many dependencies ? Also it works fine on my local machine.

Comment: @user1990524 It's very likely your local machine already has all these dependencies downloaded from when you first added them. Have you tried silverfighter's suggestion?

Comment: Yes I did, but I get new errors.

Comment: Right now I see no specific error. `go get` clones the sources from github which should be ok. after everything is local it should be ready to build. so don't forget to execute `go build ` afterwards. And you do not want to cache packages its ok for a pipeline to download them on each build.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article you need to add it to the `install` section of your `buildspec.yml` file.

```
install: 
    commands:
      - go get github.com/gorilla/mux
```

maybe it does also work to include `go get ./...` this will resolve all dependencies... but if you do not have too many it is a good practise to list them explicitly.

this is the source article: https://www.contributing.md/2017/06/30/golang-with-aws-codebuild/

Comment: I read the article and this is where I got the buildspec from. Sadly moving go get ./... to install does not help.